# How to get list of all countries and the encryption standard which is not allowed for that country

Tags: cryptography

I want to know the list of all countries and the encryption standard not allowed for that country.

Example: For some country encryption is not allowed. and for some country encryption level should not be grater than 64 bit.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to another forum? Just a thought :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The resource you are looking for is the [Crypto Law Survey](http://www.cryptolaw.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe such a list exists.
You need to research for each country and build such a list on your own. The best way is of course let a lawyer investigate that for you.

Anyway, what do you need it for? If it's a web application that resides on servers in a country X you only need to comply with that country requirements. The fact that people can access your application from anywhere in the world will not be your concern.

Comment: IANAL, but if you're providing some encryption service from the USA, for some types of encryption you can't legally provide it to the North Koreans et al.

Comment: Leave it to the users, they should know the law where they live -- refer [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

the ones I know of
Russia
Ukraine
Crimea
Egypt
Kazakhstan
Israel
Turkey
China
Pakistan

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to fully explain your answer.

Comment: The question wasn't what are the countries, but HOW TO GET the list of all countries.

Answer (score -1):

Check with a lawyer (as this data would come from the laws of that specific country, which tend to change); then make a list, e.g.

```
 <country id="US">
      <bannedcipher type="rot13" />
 </country>
```

and keep it up to date (that's the hard part). AFAIK, there's no reliable way to get this list programatically; also, the encryption allowed may vary according to the use (e.g. "In Elbonia, everybody except the military is hereby banned from using XOR").